# Is it possible to create Report on records with specific topic?

Tags: topics

This question is regarding new Topic feature salesforce launched in current release - 
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_general_topics_for_objects.htm

is it possible to create a report (Salesforce report)  for certain topics?

Example - I want to create a report on Accounts having topic as 'APAC'? I was able to create list view in account tab but not a report.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we cannot report on topics, there is already Idea posted into salesforce for this.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l12wAAA

Comment: This has been delivered in winter 15 .You may reconsider this answer .

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been delivered as per winter 15 release notes .

[image]

You can report on topics .

Comment: A report for the example scenario posted in the question is not yet possible. The Topics and Topic Assignment objects have a limited set of fields and lookup relationships to report on.

Answer (score -1):

@ Mohith Shrivastava

What the OP asks ("I want to create a report on Accounts having topic as 'APAC'") is possible using a report type based on "Topic Assignments" object.

Create a report type selecting "Topic Assignments" object. Create a report based on this new report type and include "Topic Assignment: Name" (which is nothing but the associated record) & "Topic: Name" (this is the actual "Topic") columns. That's it.

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that this question is nearly 10 years old at this point. It's very possible that this solution was not available back in 2014.

Comment: @Derek F Mohith said we need to create report based on "Topics" for OP's question but it should be based on "Topic Assignments". I added this response here so that anyone visiting this thread knows which report type to use.

Comment: lol @ Felix van Hove - did you not read my response properly?? "Topics" and "Topic Assignments" are two different report types sir. Please check the same in Setup -> Custom Report Types